# How SLURM and Pytorch handle multi-node multi-gpu training together

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing, distributed-system, slurm

I would like to ask how the gradients aggregate when being trained with multi-node multi-gpu in a cluster using Slurm to manage workload. The code is written using Pytorch.

For example when launching a script `train.py` in Slurm to train a model on 4 nodes with 4GPUs per node as below, what do the `srun` command do exactly?

```
srun python train.py
```

It is written in the documentation that `srun` is used to run a parallel job on cluster managed by Slurm. However, I would like to know what steps it performs. I imagine that it copies the script to 16 GPUs and each GPU will run the script at the same time. Is that correct?

If I use `torch.distributed.init_process_group()` in my script to handle multi-gpu training, how Slurm will handle the gradients collected from each GPU together with Pytorch? I assume that there is a master port (which is a GPU device in a node assigned by Slurm) that gathers the gradients. And all 16 GPUs in 4 nodes will transfer the gradients to this master port thanks to the `torch.distributed` package? Slurm helps to allocate resources but it does not have any role in the aggregation of the gradients?

I'm also not sure if I should launch the script using just `srun` as above or should I specify the `torch.distributed.launch` in my command as below. I want to make sure the gradients are collected correctly.

```
# NGPU equals to number of GPUs/node
export NGPU=4
srun python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=$NGPU train.py
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "I imagine that it copies the script to 16 GPUs and each GPU will run the script at the same time. Is that correct?" more likely it copies the script to 4 nodes, each of which can see 4 gpus. Each node can be thought of as an entire system, with processor(s), ram, gpus, hard disk.

Comment: @jodag-ReinstateMonica'link' Thank you for your explanation! I understood now.